# 2 PHP errors while creating new entry using Publisher

Tags: php-errors, publisher

Im having a minor issue with my channel form. The form is ment to create new entry instead of editing one. (when editing entries dont get the errors because entry_id is present).
Using latest EE 2.10.1, with Publisher 1.6.4 running on php5.6.2.

EE's docs states that when channel form doesnt find entry_id, it will create new entry, and because Publisher is somehow checking things againts entry_id, errors are thrown because there is no entry_id available.

Here is the opening tag for channel:form I have now (have tried about all variations with dif params I can think of), does anyone have any idea what I might be missing?

`{exp:channel:form channel="tapahtumat" include_jquery="no" status="open" entry_id="{segment_3}" datepicker="no" class="form-horizontal" author_only="yes" cache="no" return="{phrase:uustapahtuma}/ENTRY_ID"}`
Below is inputs cos dunno how I can add them inside code here (sorry).

input type="hidden" name="lang_id" value="{publisher:current_language_id}">
input type="hidden" name="publisher_view_status" value="draft">
input type="hidden" name="publisher_save_status" value="open">

Errors what I get are:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: entry_id
Filename: publisher/ext.publisher.php
Line Number: 594

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: entry_id
Filename: publisher/ext.publisher.php
Line Number: 601
```

Not sure what else I can tell more than I use the phrase on return param because it didnt seem to translate the URL when creating entry in different language.
I do not have drafts enabled, Im using Publisher purely for translating content.

Help would be nice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please submit this to boldminded.com/support. I don't do support here.

Comment: Was indeed a bug that Developer has fixed and provided new addon build via their bug tracker.